# Allow users to create own workflow scenarios

Tags: c#, .net, forms, content-management-system, workflow

I have such task:
allow users to create smth like template forms(from predefined controls like in any CMS for web) and some workflows to be used in that forms. For example user can create form of generating some report, and after submitting it-another form must be shown, but all that should happen dynamically without hiring developer to extend the existing code. Is it possible to give some predefined scenarios to the users and allow them to choose some actions, combining that scenarios? I know that we can write such thing, but there may be many errors while implementing that and i hope there is some ready solution..
Is there a sort of CMS for Winforms/WPF?..Can you suggest the best way to finish such task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WPF. You could let them enter the XAML in form of a text file or a text box and then execute it on runtime using [XamlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx).